# Solutions to performance issues caused by large variant size of enum

Tags: rust

I am trying to build a tree-like data structure using the `Node` representation:

```
use std::cmp::Ordering;
use std::fmt::Debug;
use std::sync::Arc;

const BRANCH_FACTOR: usize = 32;

#[derive(Debug, Clone, PartialEq, Eq, PartialOrd, Ord)]
enum Node<T> {
    Branch {
        children: [Option<Arc<Node<T>>>; BRANCH_FACTOR],
        len: usize,
    },
    RelaxedBranch {
        children: [Option<Arc<Node<T>>>; BRANCH_FACTOR],
        sizes: [Option<usize>; BRANCH_FACTOR],
        len: usize,
    },
    Leaf {
        elements: [Option<T>; BRANCH_FACTOR],
        len: usize,
    },
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=57182eb56c41280836b3193d8838d25f&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015)

The `RelaxedBranch` variant of the enum will be used rarely, sometimes not at all. Since the size of enums in Rust is defined by the size of the largest variant, `RelaxedBranch` increases overall the memory footprint of `Node` drastically. The large size of this enum causes a 20% performance hit, which is not acceptable in my case.

As an alternative to enums, I have decided to try trait objects:

```
use std::cmp::Ordering;
use std::fmt::Debug;
use std::sync::Arc;

const BRANCH_FACTOR: usize = 32;

trait Node<T>: Debug + Clone + PartialEq + Eq + PartialOrd + Ord {}

#[derive(Debug, Clone, PartialEq, Eq, PartialOrd, Ord)]
struct Branch<T> {
    children: [Option<Arc<Node<T>>>; BRANCH_FACTOR],
    len: usize,
}

#[derive(Debug, Clone, PartialEq, Eq, PartialOrd, Ord)]
struct RelaxedBranch<T> {
    children: [Option<Arc<Node<T>>>; BRANCH_FACTOR],
    len: usize,
}

#[derive(Debug, Clone, PartialEq, Eq, PartialOrd, Ord)]
struct Leaf<T> {
    elements: [Option<T>; BRANCH_FACTOR],
    len: usize,
}

impl<T> Node<T> for Branch<T> {}
impl<T> Node<T> for RelaxedBranch<T> {}
impl<T> Node<T> for Leaf<T> {}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=e0442f24603451853df08343355ca3c0&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015)

I have quickly discovered something called trait object safety :) This doesn't allow traits used for trait objects to return objects of the `Self` type, which is my case due to inheritance from `Clone`.

How can I represent a tree node without having the overhead of enums?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need trait objects here because you don't need the unbounded polymorphism they provide.

[Clippy](https://rust-lang-nursery.github.io/rust-clippy/) tells you what to do:

```
warning: large size difference between variants
  --> src/main.rs:13:5
   |
13 | /     RelaxedBranch {
14 | |         children: [Option<Arc<Node<T>>>; BRANCH_FACTOR],
15 | |         sizes: [Option<usize>; BRANCH_FACTOR],
16 | |         len: usize,
17 | |     },
   | |_____^
   |
   = note: #[warn(large_enum_variant)] on by default
help: consider boxing the large fields to reduce the total size of the enum
  --> src/main.rs:13:5
   |
13 | /     RelaxedBranch {
14 | |         children: [Option<Arc<Node<T>>>; BRANCH_FACTOR],
15 | |         sizes: [Option<usize>; BRANCH_FACTOR],
16 | |         len: usize,
17 | |     },
   | |_____^
   = help: for further information visit https://rust-lang-nursery.github.io/rust-clippy/v0.0.211/index.html#large_enum_variant
```

Switching to

```
RelaxedBranch {
    children: Box<[Option<Arc<Node<T>>>; BRANCH_FACTOR]>,
    sizes: Box<[Option<usize>; BRANCH_FACTOR]>,
    len: usize,
},
```

Reduces the size of `Node<()>` from 784 to 272. You could go further by combining all the fields into a new struct and boxing that.

Comment: 1) I know that I have not mentioned this in the original question, but thread safety is also a requirement. As far as I know, Boxes are not thread safe :( 2) Wrapping fields into a struct sounds like an interesting design solution, will try that for sure!

Comment: Since you also store a `len`, I suspect that you should actually use a `Vec` instead of your boxed array + `len`…

Comment: @Jmb Vec has a small overhead in a form of the capacity variable + I don't need power of Vec APIs at the moment :) But thanks for the suggestion, I was considering doing the same.